# How to check if value is not `blank` in this code using Java Script or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check if value is not `blank` in this code using Java Script or jQuery?

```
<select name="producttype" class="selectOption">
    <option class="selectOption" value="blank">Select something</option>
    <option class="selectOption"  value="test1">Test1</option>
    <option class="selectOption"  value="test2">Test2</option>
    <option class="selectOption"  value="test3">Test3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Next time, please post what you've tried.

Comment: @Jeffman - this time would be helpful as well.

Comment: I commented after an answer had been posted. The point seemed moot for this time around.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$(".selectOption").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "blank")
        // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("select[name=producttype]").change(function() {
    if (!(this.value == "blank"))
        console.log("not blank!");
});
```

Comment: This won't work. `this.value` is not defined for a `select` object. You will have to do `jQuery(this).val()`.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I guess this must be something recent. Previously you had to get it from `select.options[select.selectedIndex].value`. Old habits die hard, I guess. :)

Comment: It works, because it's using the DOM object with Javascript. But it looks "ugly" because it's part jQuery, part native JS.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Thanks for the explanation; learnt something new.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
if(jQuery("select.selectOption").val() !== "blank") {
    ...
}
```

Or if you're checking to see that the value is not blank on a `change` event:

```
jQuery("select.selectOption").on("change", function() {
    if(jQuery(this).val() !== "blank") {
        ...
    }
});
```